# UIView to UITextfield in xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Please anyone help me with converting this objective c code to C#

```
UITextField *field=(UITextField *)view;
```

I need is its equivalent xamarin code.

I know this is a very basic question for you people but, I'm a beginner and an early reply will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITextField field = view as UITextField;
```